# WordPress page content only in fancybox except direct click

Tags: ajax

it's really hard to describe the issue in one sentence! i tried this solution ([Load page content with AJAX using Fancybox?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129185/load-page-content-with-ajax-using-fancybox)) but that doesn't work for me, even though it seemed like it was exactly what I needed....

:( I searched so many hours now on the internet but still couldn't figure out how to get this done. I'm so totally desperate! :(

i have a custom post type where I post pages. on the website i see that content in a fancybox, when I click at these URLs. for this I created a template single-custom-post-type file without header, footer and other stuff. just content.

but google now listet all these links (i do want that), but also shows just the content of these pages, of course, because i wrote that into the template file... how can I make an exception for those who direct click on these links or do a right-click so the page will load into a new tab? in this case I want to see the full page with header, footer etc.

is there any possibility?

like for example: if onClick = open fancybox with THAT template (just content)

**Update:**

*This is my custom-post-type single-page: single-leistungen.php*

```
     <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

     <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else : ?>

<h1><?php _e('Nichts gefunden','webzone'); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

*The Javascript of the fancybox-Code:*

```
$(".leistungen").fancybox({

            padding: 20,
            wrapCSS : 'inlinebox',
                openEffect : 'elastic',
                openSpeed  : 250,
                closeEffect : 'fade',
                closeSpeed  : 150,
            type: 'ajax',

                closeClick : true,
                helpers: {
                    title : {
                        type : 'inside'
                    },
                    overlay: {
                      locked: false
                    }
                }
            });
```

*And this is how I call the page on front-page.php:*

```
<a rel="leistungen" class="leistungen fancybox.ajax" href="<?php echo get_permalink( 73 ); ?>" title="Webdesign"></a>
```

Comment: Just so it's clear: You have content that opens in a fancybox, when google links to said page, it loads the content without the header and footer, correct? What you want to do is have the content in the fancy box when necessary and look like it's part of your website ( header / footer ) when linked elsewhere ( from google ) ?

Comment: yes, thats right! just the content (text + images of WordPress page) when you click and fancybox opens, but when you open the site manually (like google does or when you open the link in new tab) I would like to see a normal WordPress page with header, footer etc.

Comment: I think you have it Howdy McGee - a directory/list of other pages content on which clicked takes user to a new browser tab displaying the full WP page. Mags You may not realize it but your stepping into a world of professionalism in-which we don't normally begin sentences with smiley faces or even use them at all. It might sound harsh but your emotions are of little concern and will get in the way. I recommend screenshots and videos mags. Tools like Jing and Lightshot. If your going to work on WordPress a lot I suggest a "beta" directory on your site, get things setup there and link us to it.

Comment: @mags Well now that the problem is clear, the next step is to post *how* you're pulling the content into the fancybox. What you need to do is separate that from the actual page template and pull just the content directly into the fancybox using something like `get_post()` or the likes. If you're unfamiliar with how to edit your question to add this information there's an *edit* button toward the bottom of your question ^_^

Comment: just updated my question, thanks! I'm thinking of so many solutions but can't get any of them to work. Can't believe there's no one out there facing the same issue!

Comment: @mags Unfortunately, I'm not versed in fancybox :/ - - - What you'd need is to keep your single post type template as a normal template, including header / footer that's for sure. The next step is to somehow have fancybox connect to *maybe* [wp_ajax](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29) to pull that posts content `$post->post_content` then send it back to fancybox for display. That's the idea anyway, hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: thank you @Howdy_McGee! I really appreciate your help. Sadly I have to admit that my knowledge isn't that great, neither :( I did a little research of wp_ajax but didn't understand a thing. Hmpf, I will keep trying to find a solution! :)